# Creating Indicator Matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

For a vector **V** of size **n x 1**, I would like to create binary indicator matrix **M** of the size **n x Max(V)** such that the row entries of **M** have **1** in the corresponding columns index, **0** otherwise.

For eg: If **V** is

```
V = [ 3
      2
      1
      4]
```

The indicator matrix should be

```
M= [ 0 0 1 0
     0 1 0 0
     1 0 0 0
     0 0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The thing about an indicator matrix like this, is it is better if you make it sparse. You will almost always be doing a matrix multiply with it anyway, so make that multiply an efficient one.

```
n = 4;
V = [3;2;1;4];
M = sparse(V,1:n,1,n,n);
M =
   (3,1)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (4,4)        1
```

If you insist on M being a full matrix, then making it so is simple after the fact, by use of full.

```
full(M)
ans =
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
```

Learn how to use sparse matrices. You will gain greatly from doing so. Admittedly, for a 4x4 matrix, sparse will not gain by much. But the example cases are never your true problem. Suppose that n was really 2000?

```
n = 2000;
V = randperm(n);
M = sparse(V,1:n,1,n,n);
FM = full(M);

whos FM M
  Name         Size                 Bytes  Class     Attributes

  FM        2000x2000            32000000  double              
  M         2000x2000               48008  double    sparse
```

Sparse matrices do not gain only in terms of memory used. Compare the time required for a single matrix multiply.

```
A = magic(2000);

tic,B = A*M;toc
Elapsed time is 0.012803 seconds.

tic,B = A*FM;toc
Elapsed time is 0.560671 seconds.
```

Answer (score 7):

a quick way to do this - if you do not require sparse matrix - is to create an identity matrix, of size at least the max(v), then to create your indicator matrix by extracting indexes from v:

```
m = max(V);
I = eye(m);
V = I(V, :);
```

Comment: can you please explain the third line of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You would like to create the Index matrix to be sparse for memory sake.  It is as easy as:

```
vSize = size(V);
Index = sparse(vSize(1),max(V));
for i = 1:vSize(1)
    Index(i, v(i)) = 1;
end
```

I've used this myself, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, similar to `sparse` but with [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
V = [3; 2; 1; 4];
M = accumarray([(1:numel(V)).' V], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine the column index in `V` with a row index to create a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), then use that to fill `M` (initialized to zeroes):

```
M = zeros(numel(V), max(V));
M((1:numel(V))+(V.'-1).*numel(V)) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
M=sparse(V,1:size(V,1),1)';
```

will produce a sparse matrix that you can use in calculations as a full version.
You could use full(M) to "inflate" M to actually store zeros.