# Matlab/Octave 1-of-K representation

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a y of size 5000,1 (matrix), which contains integers between 1 and 10. I want to expand those indices into a 1-of-10 vector. I.e., y contains 1,2,3... and I want it to "expand" to:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What is the best way to do that?

I tried:

```
Y = zeros(5000,10); Y(y) = 1;
```

but it didn't work.

It works for vectors though:

if `y = [2 5 7]`, and `Y = zeros(1,10)`, then `Y(y) = [0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Indicator Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n=5
Y = ceil(10*rand(n,1))
Yexp = zeros(n,10);
Yexp(sub2ind(size(Yexp),1:n,Y')) = 1
```

Also, consider using sparse, as in: [Creating Indicator Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix/6150845#6150845).

Comment: Are there relative merits/demerits to bsxfun v. sub2ind?

Comment: @Frank: this is indexing-based, mine involves making equality-comparisons... Would be interesting to see how they compare in terms of performance

Comment: I checked the performance. The sub2ind solution is slightly faster than the bsxfun solution.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following:

```
y = randi([1 10],[5 1]);       %# vector of 5 numbers in the range [1,10]
yy = bsxfun(@eq, y, 1:10)';    %# 1-of-10 encoding
```

Example:

```
>> y'
ans =
     8     8     4     7     2
>> yy
yy =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, give or take a transpose :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Frank: I also believe the Statistics Toolbox has a somewhat similar function [DUMMYVAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dummyvar.html)

Answer (score 3):

While sparse may be faster and save memory, an answer involving eye() would be more elegant as it is faster than a loop and it was introduced during the octave lecture of that class

Here is an example for 1 to 4

```
V = [3;2;1;4];
I = eye(4);
Vk = I(V, :);
```

Comment: What works for me is eye(K)(V,:) which is similar to yours but condenses lines 2 and 3 into one line. More usefully though, K is number of possible classes, not actually present  classes, so for example if there were 10 possible outcomes of which 4 actually were present, it would work more correctly and more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cellfun operations:

```
function vector = onehot(vector,decimal)
    vector(decimal)=1;
end
aa=zeros(10,2);
dec=[5,6];
%split into columns
C=num2cell(aa,1);
D=num2cell(dec,1);
onehotmat=cellfun("onehot",C,D,"UniformOutput",false);
output=cell2mat(onehotmat);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you mean:

```
y = [2 5 7];
Y = zeros(5000,10);
Y(:,y) = 1;
```

After the question edit, it should be this instead:

```
y = [2,5,7,9,1,4,5,7,8,9....]; //(size (1,5000))
for i = 1:5000
    Y(i,y(i)) = 1;
end
```

Comment: This will set the entire y columns to 1.

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing the loop, which is the most obvious solution :-)

Comment: question wasn't very clear until Amro edited it :), be sure to accept the other guy's answer

Comment: His question literally is what the best way of doing it is, and you pose a for loop XD.