# Matlab, Integer vector to binary matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector with N elements, all integers 1-M. I want to convert this to a NxM matrix with each row containing only zeros except for the i:th element set to one, i being the integer in the vector.

For example:
[1 1 3] => [1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1]

I currently do this in a loop, like this:

```
y_vec = zeros(m, num_labels);
for i = 1:m
    y_vec(i, y(i)) = 1;
end
```

Is there a  way to do this without a loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Indicator Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix), or [Matlab/Octave 1-of-K representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054258/matlab-octave-1-of-k-representation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
y = [1 1 3];
m = length(y);
num_labels = max(y);

%# initialize y_vec
y_vec = zeros(m,num_labels);

%# create a linear index from {row,y}
idx = sub2ind(size(y_vec),1:m,y);

%# set the proper elements of y_vec to 1
y_vec(idx) = 1;
```

Comment: linear indices can be created by another way, without using any function 
idx=(y'-1)*m+(1:m)'  
instead of 
idx = sub2ind(size(y_vec),1:m,y);

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox, the command `dummyvar` does exactly this.

```
>> dummyvar([1 1 3])
ans =
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

(This has been asked in [Creating Indicator Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix) and [Matlab/Octave 1-of-K representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054258/matlab-octave-1-of-k-representation/).)

My favorite answer is [woodchips'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix/6150845#6150845) `sparse(1:n,labels,1,n,m);`.