# Matlab/Octave one-liner for a n-vector with a 1 in the i-th position

Tags: matlab, octave

For example, given `i=5` and and `n=8`, I want to generate `[0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0]`. Specifically, I want to generate the vector `v` so that:

```
v = zeros(n,1);
v(i) = 1;
```

Is there a (reasonable) way to do this in one line?

Comment: possible duplicates (generalization of this question): [Creating Indicator Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix), [Matlab/Octave 1-of-K representation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8054258/97160), or [Matlab, Integer vector to binary matrix without loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8116991/97160)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another solution using [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) to create an `n` length row vector with a 1 in the `i`th position:

```
v = sparse(1,i,1,1,n)
```

The advantage is that for large `n`, this is also memory efficient and can be used as usual in matrix calculations. If you ever need the full vector, just use [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/full.html).

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer for the memory considerations.

Answer (score 14):

Another solution:

```
I = eye(n);

v = I(:, i);
```

Actually, you can have a vector `y` of numbers from 1 to n and get vectors like this for each element:

```
v = I(:, y);
```

You can see my [blog post](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2012/06/gentle-intro-to-octave.html) for the details on this general solution.

Answer (score 13):

One way is `[1:8]'==5`, or more generally `[1:n]'==i`

Comment: Good solution. But it is not *exactly* the same, since you get logical instead of double. I would do double( [1:n]'==i );

Comment: +1 for the answer, +1 for Andrey's comment. The double is necessary to be the _exact_ answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
n = 8;
p = 4;
arrayfun(@str2double,dec2bin(2^(p-1),n))
```

And another one (Creates a row vector):

```
circshift( [1 zeros(1,n-1)],[0 p]);
```

Or a column vector:

```
circshift( [1 ; zeros(n-1,1)],[p 0]);
```

---

Here is another one:

```
subsref( eye(n), struct('type','()', 'subs',{{ p,':' }}))
```