# Generate boolean matrix by predicate on row and column

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have the following vector:

```
y = [1; 3; 2; 3; 1];
```

All its values are between `1` and `n` (in this case, `3`) and denote different options.

I want to create a matrix of size `size(y, 1)` x `n` whose rows correpond to `y` values:

```
1 0 0 % because y(1) = 1
0 0 1 % because y(2) = 3
0 1 0 % because y(3) = 2
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

One way to do this would be

```
Y = zeros(size(y, 1), num_labels);
for i = 1:m
    Y(i, y(i)) = 1;
end
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe in a single expression?
Basically, what I need is to generate a matrix with boolean predicate `(i, j) => j == y(i)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Indicator Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this if `a` is a column vector

```
a =  [1; 3; 2; 3; 1];

bsxfun(@eq, a, [1:max(a)])
```

and this if it is a row vector

```
a =  [1; 3; 2; 3; 1]';

bsxfun(@eq, a', [1:max(a)])
```

Comment: +1 That's really cool. I see a new powerful use of `bsxfun` every week!

Comment: This is the most elegant solution so far! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox, the command `dummyvar` does exactly what you need.

```
>> y = [1; 3; 2; 3; 1];
>> dummyvar(y)
ans =
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, +1 from me. Unfortunately I don't have ST out of the box in Octave so I'm sticking with H.Muster's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) after initializing the matrix as follows:

```
y = [1; 3; 2; 3; 1];
m = length(y);
n = max(y);

Y = zeros(m, n);
Y(sub2ind(size(Y), 1:m, y')) = 1

Y =

     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
```

The trick here is to know that the corresponding rows of `y` go from `1` to `m` one by one.

Answer (score 2):

```
accumarray([(1:length(y)).' y], 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Dmitri Bouianov on Coursera discussion forum, this also works:

```
Y = eye(num_labels)(y, :);
```

This solution uses elements of `y` to as indices to select rows from an identity matrix.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to achieve result

Answer (score 1):

In Octave (at least as of 3.6.3, not sure when it was introduced), you can use broadcasting to do this extremely easily. It works like this:

```
Y = y==1:3
```

(if y is a row matrix, you need to transpose it first - if you want to have Y transposed instead, use y==(1:3)')