# Incrementing column i in row A(i) of B

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Is there a better way to do this for-loop?

```
for i = find(A > 42)
    B(A(i), i) = B(A(i), i) + 1;
end
```

`A` is an integer array. `B` is a `max(A)`×`length(A)` matrix.

Example:

```
A = reshape(magic(3), 1, 9); %# 8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
B = zeros(max(A), length(A));
for i = find(A > 3)
    B(A(i), i) = B(A(i), i) + 1;
end

B = [
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
]
```

Comment: Can you give a small-matrix example of what you're trying to accomplish so it is easier to understand the objective?

Comment: @tmpearce, I added a small example.

Comment: @tmpearce I fixed the title. Is it better understandable what I want to do now?

Comment: Yep, this is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend linear indexing for this case.  Convert your row/column subindices into linear indices with [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html).

```
i = find(A > 3);
si = sub2ind(size(B),A(i),i);
B(si) = B(si) + 1;
```

You can combine this into a one-liner if you want, I left it as multiple lines for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
B = zeros(max(A), length(A)); 
inds = find(A > thresh);
B(sub2ind(size(B),A(inds),inds)) = 1;
```

Comment: looks like your solution is better than mine in that I didn't know about sub2ind.  But my solution is better than yours in that he asked to increment B, not set it to 1.  I assume he has more than one matrix "A" he is processing and wants to accumulate results in B.  (We essentially have the same solution, I obviously took too long to come up with mine).

Answer (score 1):

This is compact, loopless, and it works:

```
INDICES = A(:) + length(A)*[0:length(A)-1]';                          %#' 
INDICES(A<42) = [];
B(INDICES) = B(INDICES)+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150845/97160)):

```
idx = find(A>3);
B = full(sparse(A(idx), idx, 1, max(A), length(A)));
```

Comment: Nice to know this syntax for `sparse`, too, but here it is less useful for me. I have many `A`s and one B where I do the counting. I should have made that more clear in my question. :-/ Actually I don't know if your solution (w/o `full`) or tmpearce solution would be faster. If I have some time to spare I'll look into that.

Comment: @kay: If I understood correctly, you could simply accumulate the counts in B: `B = zeros(..);` then `B = B + full(sparse(..))` for each A

Comment: Yes, exactly. But why would I need the `full`?

Comment: @kay: you don't need it, I just assumed you were working with dense matrices. You could initialize B as: `B = sparse(max(A),length(A));` then accumulate in B for every A: `B = B + sparse(..);`. Then optionally call `B = full(B);` at the end