# Creating Categorical Variables in Octave (implementing dummyvar)

Tags: matlab, octave

So within a data file that I would like to pass into an octave function, I have a categorical field, like this:

```
group =

msie-7
msie-8
msie-7
msie-8
msie-9
firefox-15
chrome-21
chrome-21
firefox-15
msie-7
msie-8
msie-9
..
```

I would like to turn this into a series of dummy variables (similar to the factor function in R). For some reason though, my installation of Octave does not recognize the `dummyvars` function.

```
octave-3.2.4.exe:16> dummyvars(group)
error: `dummyvars' undefined near line 16 column 1
octave-3.2.4.exe:16> dummyvar(group)
error: `dummyvar' undefined near line 16 column 1
```

1. Any idea why this is the case?
2. How would I go about writing a function to work around this? I have functions in octave designed for regularized logistic regression analysis, but this inability to handle categorical variables is a big set back.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using **cat2bin**. This function is available in the 'nan' package in Octave-Forge.

To install the package, use **pkg install -forge nan**.
Once the install is complete, load the package using **pkg load nan**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`dummyvar` is from the Matlab Statistics Toolbox.

To learn about how to implement something similar, search for "indicator matrix".  For example: [Creating Indicator Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix/6150845#6150845)