# How to change elements of a matrix with reference to a vector of column indices without using for-loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

I have `a` matrix

```
a =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
```

and `b` vector

```
b =

   1   2   3   4   5   5
```

I want to replace value of each row in `a` matrix with reference value of `b` matrix value and finally generate a matrix as follows without using for loop.

```
a_new =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   1
```

if first element of `b, b(1) = 1` so change take first row of `a` vector and make first element as 1 because `b(1) = 1`.

How can I implement this without using for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Indicator Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You only need to build a [linear index](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) from `b` and use it to fill the values in `a`:

```
a = zeros(6,5); % original matrix
b = [1 2 3 4 5 5]; % row or column vector with column indices into a
ind = (1:size(a,1)) + (b(:).'-1)*size(a,1); % build linear index
a(ind) = 1; % fill value at those positions
```

Comment: How  can I implement same if b is row vector?

Comment: What do you mean? `b` _is_ a row vector in my example and in your question. Do you mean a column? What should the result be then?

Comment: sorry column vector. In actual case 'a' is a matrix of size 5000x10 and 'b' is a vector with size 5000x1

Comment: @manoos Please see edit. `b` can now be a row or a column. I'm assuming that `b` still contains the _column_ indices into  `a`

Answer (score 2):

Same as [**Luis Mendo's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39613334/2605073), but using the dedicated function [**`sub2ind`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
a( sub2ind(size(a),(1:numel(b)).',b(:)) ) = 1
```

Comment: How can I implement same if b is row vector?

Answer (score 1):

Also via the subscript to indices conversion way,

```
a = zeros(6,5);
b = [1 2 3 4 5 5];
idx = sub2ind(size(a), [1:6], b); % 1:6 just to create the row index per b entry
a(idx) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

any of these methods works in Octave:

```
bsxfun(@eq,  [1:5 5]',(1:5))

[1:5 5].' == (1:5)
```